# Why even use kinematic bodies? box2d

Tags: c++, box2d

Why should you even use kinematic bodies instead of dynamic bodies with no gravity? I mean a dynamic body can also collide with static bodies and have some other adjustable parameters that kinematic bodies do not have, right. Therefore, I would really love to hear why you would want to do this and if it even can be lead to some advantages.

Your time is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using a search engine for the words "kinematic bodies"? Because the top results for me are blog posts discussing exactly your question

Comment: Also the [official docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#kinematic-bodies) says this: *"Kinematic bodies are great for things where you, the programmer, want to be in full control of a body's motion, such as a moving platform in a platform game."*

Comment: I have put a comment to Louis' answer, please take a look. Thanks, also for your comments :-)

Comment: I've seen the comment and it makes your question unclear - do you want to have the body in question have collision or not? If yes then you can't use a kinematic body, if no then using a dynamic body would be a waste (in terms of setup code) and potentially cost performance (a physics engine could handle updating of kinematic bodies differently since they have fewer constraints)

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of what you want `b2World::Step` to do to the body. Basically this method's body related post-conditions are as follows:

- Static bodies are unmoved.
- Kinetic bodies are moved based on their previous velocities.
- Dynamic bodies are moved based on their previous velocities, gravity, applied forces, applied impulses, masses, damping, and the restitution and friction values of their fixtures when they experience collisions.

So kinematic bodies can be useful when the only thing that you want to have happen to the body is to have it moved based on a velocity you'd given it.

Comment: But in the case of that I only want to move the body using velocity, couldn't I also just use a dynamic body with no gravity as much as a kinematic body?? And thanks

Comment: @asd Yes. A dynamic body would also be interacted with other dynamic bodies differently than a kinematic body would. And maybe you want how that interaction is done in the step. Or maybe you don't. The kinematic choice provides a different option in regard to how interaction with other bodies is handled by the step method.